# Converting file geodatabase with coded domains to PostgreSQL / PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, convert, file-geodatabase

We have several file gdb's and would like to convert these to Postgres / PostGIS. We've used ogr2ogr to transfer these files; however, some of the fields are stored as [coded domains](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Domains_toolset/00170000001t000000/) and the fields are not decoded in the transfer. Coded domains are stored in a separate table.

For example, a column design quality could belong to the general domain quality. Quality could then be coded as '1=low, 2=medium, 3=high'. This is to enforce that only certain values are used, for instance in a survey. Ogr2ogr reads the values 1, 2, and 3, but not the accompanying text.

Would anybody know how to include these domains in the transfer from gdb to Postgres / PostGIS?

We could convert to file gdb's to an ArcSDE database if this is easier; however shapefiles are not preferred due to column truncation.

This question was posted earlier [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709546/convert-arcgis-gdb-with-coded-domains-to-postgres-postgis).

Comment: Coded domains are the equivalent of constraints in a db?

Comment: Coded domains are stored in a separate table. For example, a column design quality could belong to the general domain quality. Quality could then be coded as '1=low, 2=medium, 3=high'. This is to enforce that only certain values are used, for instance in a survey. Ogr2ogr reads the values 1, 2 and 3 and not the accompanying text.

Comment: If you have SDE just copy/paste using ArcCatalog. Copies the data, domains and subtypes.

Comment: This PostgreSQL/PostGIS answer to an Oracle question may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10397/is-it-possible-to-create-domains-for-an-oracle-non-sde-database/10487#10487

Comment: Database domains aren't necessarily recognized by the consuming program. The issue here is that descriptions are text and the values are (usually) numeric. That would involve a fundamental change of data type for the field. You can export your domains to table, join and then export to *lock in* the values but then you end up with two fields, one numeric and the other text, describing the same information... to easy to get out-of-step, best to delete the numeric field after exporting if you want the text.

Comment: I usually export the featureclasses to shapefile in ArcGIS. That way the domains are converted to the actual values. Afyer That I export to postGIS

Answer (score 3):

Well, before you convert the database, you could run the Domain to Table geoprocessing tool http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Domain_To_Table/001700000022000000/ which should convert a domain to a stand-alone table that you could put in the database.  Then, you should be able to just convert the database, including stand-alone tables in the database.  Finally, at the end (or before you do the database conversion for that matter), you could do a join between the Feature Class attribute tables and the domain table, or you could even use a join to calculate the domain description value into the relevant feature classes as a new field.  Anyway, I hope that gives you some ideas, and let me know if it doesn't make sense and I'll try and clarify.